# why primitive type has 'Object' class methods?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner at C# language and currently in a great confusion regarding the following thing

Like, when I simply declare and initialize

```
int i = 10;  //A simple variable of primitive data type int
```

I tried experimenting and tried using (.) operator with it as one does when trying to access members of a class.

in autocompletion, I was bewildered seeing `Object` class methods that I could override.

What is happening here? And Why?

Comment: `int` is only slightly special, otherwise it behaves like any other `struct`. `Struct`s can have methods.

Comment: Are all primitive types special?

Comment: Can you explain why you find this confusing? `int` inherits the members of `Object` because `int` derives from `Object`.  All class, struct and delegate types in C# derive from Object (except Object).  You get the members of a class because all structs derive from a class. Why is that surprising?

Comment: I recommend against using the term "primitive type" in C#. The term is not clearly defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think that my comment could have been confusing. All "primitive types" (`byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, and their (un)signed variants) are exposed as structs. All structs can have methods.

Comment: @EricLippert I have studied Java before and there was nothing like this thing in it.

Comment: @Mr.J: C# is not Java.  But C# and Java are similar in a lot of ways. In Java you have `int` and `Integer` as the unboxed and boxed forms of the integer type. In C#, `int` and `Integer32` are both the same unboxed type; boxing happens automatically when an `int` is converted to `Object` in C#. If you use methods of `Object` on an `int` then either the method is dispatched to an override, or the `int` is boxed, depending.

Comment: @EricLippert But they say it is very similar. You are right,  they are not really `primitive` then. Also does that mean they have different sizes as well?

Comment: Does what have different sizes? Boxed and unboxed integers? Sure. Boxed integers have a 32 or 64 bit reference that refers to an object with a header.  Unboxed integers are just 32 bits, end of story.

Comment: Do you mean does byte and int have different sizes? Sure. Bytes are one byte, ints are four.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your explaination and time. But what's up with the downvote? I am pretty sure any newbie shifting from java to c# would love to clear this confusion

Comment: The question is vague, unclear, shows no effort of research on your own, and omitted key details. Any one of those is a good reason to downvote and vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". There's good advice available on SO on how to ask precise, clear, well-researched, answerable questions that contain the details necessary to enable a good answer; if you want to learn how to write better questions, start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EricLippert I know comments are not to say 'Thanks'. But Still, Thank you so much sir! It was an honour that you took the time and answered mine. Got *goosebumps*. And Sorry, I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Unlike *Java*, *C#* doesn't have any special *primitive types*, `int` is an ordinary class which is inherited from `Object` and thus `int` has all `Object`s methods